# What is the best way to inject middleware between wordpress and SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, wordpress

I am looking for the way to get all wordpress DB requests, from all plugins that are using default wp_query. I need to filter all queries by pattern and if it matches, I need to query this statement to another DB.
Please suggest how can I listen for all SQL queries ? OR there is another way to do this ?

Comment: Is this for a plugin? :P

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use a profiler trace?

Comment: can I do this directly in php code, intercept query and do some stuff, the idea is to filter some queries and query another database from php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want in your sql configuration you can uncomment the log line

```
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.

log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log /* Line to uncomment */
```

After you can put your log file everywhere and read it  with php for make what you want.

Or you can use the plugin way

https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-recorder/

Comment: Thank for the plugin reference , can I do this directly in php code, intercept query and do some stuff.

Comment: Sure you can do this with the  "pre_get_posts" hook, some informations for you.         http://www.remicorson.com/modifying-the-current-query-with-pre_get_posts/                    https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: Your comment is exactly what I am was looking for, thank you a lot, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do this with the "pre_get_posts" hook, some informations for you.

remicorson.com/modifying-the-current-query-with-pre_get_posts

codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts